# Открытие попапов по ссылке без уникального id

Tags: jquery

У меня есть структура вида:

```
<div>

<div><a href="#popup"><div>
<div><a href="#popup"><div>
<div><a href="#popup"><div>

</div>
```

И есть jQuery, который открывает попап:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $(".container").empty();
    $("#сontent").appendTo(".container");
   $('a[href="#popup"]').click(function(){
         $('.gallety').trigger('display');
        }, 200);
});
});
```

**#сontent** это рандомный идентификатор и блок, который подставляется в содержимое моего попапа (выглядит как набор цифр и я не могу управлять его названием, и в нем нет какой-либо последовательности).

И я не могу присвоить своим ссылкам какой-либо id, возможно ли открывать попапы исходя из местоположения ссылок? Т.е первая ссылка делала бы `$("#сontent-324").appendTo(".container")`, вторая `$("#сontent-2435").appendTo(".container")`, и т. д. И как это можно аккуратнее оформить в jQuery

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Igor я сам сейчас перечитываю и ничего не понимаю. Но по сути все сводится к тому что мне нужно выполнять разную функцию по клику на одинаковые ссылки. И вся разница этой функции заключается в содержимом элемента с произвольным названием, т.е $("#сontent-234324").appendTo(".container")